# How to send server request on second last item comes in listview?

Tags: android

I have a fragment containing swipe to refresh and listview which add some data when I scroll down listview there is a footer containing progressbar is shown to me ,and send request to server and adding more data in listview ,problem is that when footer is visible it send request to server back to back ,I think it is because footer is also counted as listview item ,but can't understand .I want when 2nd last itme of listview comes then send request not on last .please tell how can I do that

code for listview scroll listener
"-

```
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    if (scrollState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
        Log.i("a", "scrolling stopped...");
    }
}

@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        if (firstVisibleItem+visibleItemCount==totalItemCount&&totalItemCount!=0) {
            if (isloading == false) {
                // It is time to add new data. We call the listener
                isloading = true;
                if (NetworkUtil.isConnected(getActivity())) {
                    m_n_DefaultRecordCount = 5;// increment of record count by 5 on next load data
                    m_n_DeafalutLastCount = m_n_DeafalutLastCount + 5;// same here.....as above
                    String itemscount = String.valueOf(m_ListView.getAdapter().getCount());
                    System.out.println("Toatal item:-" + itemscount);

                    sz_RecordCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DefaultRecordCount);// convert int value to string
                    sz_LastCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DeafalutLastCount);// convert int value to string /////
                    loadmoreData();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please check internet connection !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Footer will bot be considered as Item.You can go through this link [On Demand Loading](http://benjii.me/2010/08/endless-scrolling-listview-in-android/)

It shows yo create a Custom scroll Listener.